# How to run another serve after node server has started using shell script?

Tags: node.js, shell, ionic2

I want to write a script which basically runs my node server first and after only node server has started I want to run another script. How can I implement this using shell script?

Right now I have done this so far

```
echo "Going inside NodeServer folder";
cd ./../Server-Node
echo "Starting Node Server";
npm start
echo 'Going inside Project Folder';
cd ./../ionicApp
ionic serve
```

Comment: I'm guessing Linux or unix like OS from your forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple hack is to use `npm start &` add a `sleep 15` on the line after it (or adjust accordingly to the avg time the start takes).

Note: to terminate the node process you might have to run a command to kill it [stop all instances of node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server)

Otherwise you'll want to look at some stuff here [NPM run parallel task, but wait until resource is available to run second task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609152/npm-run-parallel-task-but-wait-until-resource-is-available-to-run-second-task)

Answer (score 1):

I found out this later. adding modified script

```
echo "Going inside Server-Node";
cd ./../Server-Node
echo "Starting Node Server";
npm start & echo OK
echo 'Going inside ionic-Project';
cd ./../learn-ionic
echo 'Starting ionic server';
ionic serve
```