# How do you correctly use parallelshell with npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am trying to use parallelshell with my node project on Windows to run two processes at the same time.

Here is the scripts section of my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "npm run watch:all",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"lite": "lite-server",
"scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
"watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
```

}

When I run the command `npm start` I get this error log:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "options.cwd" property must be of type string. Received type function
at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:420:11)
at spawn (child_process.js:522:38)
at C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\development\online_classes\coursera_uhk_web_dev\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\parallelshell\index.js:104:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\development\online_classes\coursera_uhk_web_dev\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\parallelshell\index.js:100:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 watch:all: `parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run lite"`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 watch:all script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I can run the commands `npm run watch:scss` and `npm run lite` individually and they work fine, but I am not able to run the parallelshell command.

Thank you!

Comment: The solution which worked for me is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53467253/6650315

Answer (score 40):

**Try downgrading the parallelshell version from 3.0.2 to 3.0.1**

According to the statement, it is just a temporary fix.

https://github.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/issues/57

Below is the command line syntax to for downgrading **parallelshell**:

```
sudo npm uninstall --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.2

sudo npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1
```

It worked for me.

Hope this helps and let us know.

Comment: It works with me and I am using italic_ **bold** `ubuntu 18.04` and  italic_ **bold** `node v14.0.0`, Thanks

Comment: It helps, thanks for the answer. thumb up!!

Comment: Yea, this worked for me as well. Thanks! Such a strange error.

Answer (score 7):

parallelshell is giving active errors at every use. Instead of parallelshell the alternative here is to use **npm-run-all** dev-dependency.

install npm-run-all

```
npm install --save-dev npm-run-all
```

then make active changes in scripts of package.json shown below.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "dev": "npm-run-all -p watch:scss lite"
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

All correct to be run on Windows OS. Just simply try to install parallelshell@3.0.1:

```
npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1
```

and then call `npm start` again.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to incompatibility of the *npm* with the version of *parallelshell*.
Try downgrading it to 3.0.1 by using:

```
npm i --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1
```

Worked for me 100%.

Answer (score 1):

change a line in your ***node_modules/parallelshell/index.js:105***  file

from: `cwd: process.versions.node < '8.0.0' ? process.cwd : process.cwd(),`

---

to: `cwd: parseInt(process.versions.node) < 8 ? process.cwd : process.cwd(),`

---

reference: [Problem running parallelshell Nodejs script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461626/problem-running-parallelshell-nodejs-script/53467253#53467253?newreg=6e9a1c97804547b6b3eea50f13b9ba5a)

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me, instead of escaping your double quotes you could use single quotes inside the double quotes.

Not sure if it will make a difference.

```
"watch:all": "parallelshell 'npm run watch:scss' 'npm run lite'"
```

Comment: The OP asks about the Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is different for MAC and Windows machines.
User single quotes on MAC and "\ "\ on windows.
Also downgrade to parallelshell to 3.0.1 to work with \"

Answer (score 0):

I changed to use *concurrently* package, and it works well for me on win64, the method mentioned is in the [post](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/10).
I just simply use 
 *"watch:all": "concurrently \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""*
 to replace
 *"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""*

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue can not be fixed using npm audit fix. All you can do is to copy the actual index.js file of parallelshell into your node_modules directory.

So to do it below are the instructions:

1. Go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/master/index.js

2. Copy the content here.

3. Now go to the directory of your project, it may be something like /project/node_modules/parallelshell/index.js

4. Inside the index.js replace the contents with the one you copied from the link in Step 1.

5. Save the file and exit.

Hope this fix will work for you.

Comment: Please edit your answer. Instead of linking to some code, post the differences between `node_modules/parallelshell/index.js` and your link here. After that put the link at the bottom as a reference. The link may change or break one day. Another suggestion is to use a permalink like this one (linking to the version of index.js at a certain commit): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/8fd83e217a015b2c8c8e33ff1e836db02b7bfe8e/index.js 
This link should always display the same content rather than the latest version in the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still running into errors after altering the index.js or after demoting to 3.0.1 version, a better alternative would be using npm-run-all