# Problem running parallelshell Nodejs script

Tags: node.js, json, sass, npm-scripts, lite-server

In my package.json file I have the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "sass": "node-sass -o sass/ css/",
    "watch:sass": "onchange 'sass/*.scss' -- npm run sass",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell 'npm run watch:sass' 'npm run lite'"
  }
```

Whenever I run my code I got this error message:

```
 crs@1.0.0 start /home/hazem/crs
> npm run watch:all


> crs@1.0.0 watch:all /home/hazem/crs
> parallelshell 'npm run watch:sass' 'npm run lite'

child_process.js:422
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('options.cwd', 'string', options.cwd);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "options.cwd" property must be of type string. Received type function
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:422:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:537:38)
    at /home/hazem/crs/node_modules/parallelshell/index.js:104:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hazem/crs/node_modules/parallelshell/index.js:100:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crs@1.0.0 watch:all: `parallelshell 'npm run watch:sass' 'npm run lite'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the crs@1.0.0 watch:all script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hazem/.npm/_logs/2018-11-24T19_19_24_809Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crs@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the crs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hazem/.npm/_logs/2018-11-24T19_19_24_823Z-debug.log
```

So, in this case, what could be the problem? is it something wrong with the script? Or a bug in Parallelshell script in nodejs?

Comment: See open issue [#67](https://github.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/issues/67) in the projects github repo.

Comment: @RobC Appreciate it, fixed!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a problem with Parallelshell that has to be fixed manually;

go to the file:

```
node_modules/parallelshell/index.js:105
```

Then change this line:

```
cwd: process.versions.node < '8.0.0' ? process.cwd : process.cwd(),
```

To this:

```
cwd: parseInt(process.versions.node) < 8 ? process.cwd : process.cwd(),
```

It's done!

Comment: If you are having trouble finding this line, its on line number 105(index.js).

Answer (score 0):

cwd:

```
parseInt(process.versions.node) < 8 ? process.cwd : process.cwd()
```

If you still face problems after doing this, you have to downgrade the version of paralleshell using this line:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

It works for me as I have facing similar issues parallelshell 3.2.2 doesnot cope with my node so I have to downgrade it