# Sequential NPM script after "react-scripts start"

Tags: reactjs, electron, package.json, npm-scripts

Working on an Electron app with React. Right now, to get things started, I run the typical `npm start` command which runs the `react-scripts start` script.

This starts the dev server. Once the dev server is started, I open a second terminal window and run a script to start electron `npm run start-electron` which opens my React app in the Electron window.

This works as expected, but I was curious if there was a way to create a script that would:

- Start the dev server
- Wait for dev server to be started
- Then start electron

I tried setting up a sequential script in package.json but it only starts up the dev server. For example `npm run start && npm run start-electron`.

This isn't make or break. The two terminal option works fine, just didn't know if this was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I use `concurrently` to do it within my projects

`npm i concurrently`

and add a new script, let's call it `dev` for example, then in your scripts:

`"dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run start-electron\""`

All that remains to do now is `npm run dev`

Comment: Getting closer! It looks like this runs at the same time, because I get an electron window right away, but the dev server hasn't started yet, so it's a blank screen. I can refresh once the dev server starts up, which isn't a big deal. That said, is it possible to force the second script to wait for the first one to complete?

Comment: I would go for just a refresh/doing whatever you need to do, but if you really want you can implement it by combining concurrently with wait-on, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192578

Comment: Yes. Just tried combining concurrently and wait-on and now I don't need to refresh. The electron script doesn't run until my local dev server is started

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same situation, and below script work for me (remember to install [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on))

```
  "scripts": {
    "start-reactjs": "PORT=25610 react-scripts start",
    "start-electron": "wait-on http://localhost:25610 && electron .",
    "start": "npm run start-electron & npm run start-reactjs"
  }
```

Comment: I needed a combination of `concurrently` and `wait-on` in order to successfully run a script exactly after the server has been started.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script in the root directory with extension `.sh`
it could contain all operations for you

```
  npm start
  npm run start-electron
```

The second approach you could create a custom script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "customStart":"npm run start && npm run start-electron"
  },
```

to run this script

```
npm run customStart
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried the sequential run techniques and they are only executing the first half. Might be something to do with "react-scripts start" I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) npm module. It has different purpose, but it could work for your scenario.

From documentation:

> This command is meant to be used with NPM script commands. If you have
> a "start server", and "test" script names for example, you can start
> the server, wait for a url to respond, then run tests. When the test
> process exits, the server is shut down.
>
> ```
>     "scripts": {
>         "start-server": "npm start",
>         "test": "mocha e2e-spec.js",
>         "ci": "start-server-and-test start-server http://localhost:8080 test"
>         } 
>     }
> ```
>
> To execute all tests simply run npm run ci.

Another alternative could be [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) combined with [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on) as @Slim said

From documentation:

> wait-on will wait for period of time for a file to stop growing before
> triggering availability which is good for monitoring files that are
> being built. Likewise wait-on will wait for period of time for other
> resources to remain available before triggering success.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `concurrently`

```
npm i concurrently
```

In my package.json

```
"build": "concurrently \"npm run build-react\" && npm run build-jsx",
```

I'm using it to build an Adobe extension using react, and I need to bundle my extendscript **after** the `react-scripts build`, which would otherwise delete my `.jsxbin`